# open google map via launch_url with place name

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm using the below code to launch map in flutter of specified location, but the map showing coordinates instead.

```
 launchUrl(
Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${locationLat},${locationLong}'),
mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

How to show-place name while displaying map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the map to show the location, you should specify the location name instead of the coordinates in the query argument, start by encoding the name.

```
String locationEncoded = Uri.encodeFull(locationName);
launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/search/api=1&query=$locationEncoded'), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

If you only have the coordinates and do not know the location name, then you can use geocoding https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding to get places infos:

```
List<Placemark> placeMarks = [];
placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);

if (placeMarks.isNotEmpty) {
  location = placeMarks.first.locality?? '';
}
```

**BONUS**

If the Google map application is installed on the device, you can use intent action for Android https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents and IOS https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme so it will open the Google map application instead of the web page.

The full code will look like:

```
  var uri = Uri.parse('geo:$latitude,$longitude?q=$locationEncoded');
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    uri = Uri.parse('comgooglemaps://?center=$latitude,$longitude&q=$locationEncoded');
  }

  if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
    await launchUrl(uri);
  }
  else {
    launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$locationEncoded'));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this simple code**

```
String placeName = "Commercial Market";
String url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/$placeName";

launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```